# Intellij: Cannot select "Groovy" in "Add Framework Support"

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, frameworks, ide

I would like to add Groovy support to my project in Intellij Idea 2018.1. But when I open "Add Framework Support..." from the project context menu, I don't see "Groovy" in the list of frameworks:

[image]

I have Groovy installed on my machine and configured it as a global library in in IntelliJ:

[image]

Not sure whether this should be possible, but I also cannot add Groovy as an SDK:

[image]

I added Groovy as a module dependency:

[image]

My underlying problem is that IntelliJ does not properly recognize Groovy code, e.g. I get

```
Cannot resolve symbol `String`
```

when I use the `String` class:

[image]

Any hints on how I can make Groovy available as a Framework and an SDK?

**Solution**

Thanks to CrazyCoder pointing me to the broken JDK. Fixing the JDK and adding Groovy as a module dependency fixed the problem. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Comment: Groovy is added as a library, not as a framework. Just add the library to the module dependencies: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Comment: Clarify the problem what exactly didn't work.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder - hope clarification helps. AFAIK, it should be possible to use Groovy as an SDK, which is not possible for me.

Comment: Your JDK path is in red which indicates the problem (JDK classpath is also empty). Remove JDK configuration and add it again. Then make sure the project/modules are set to use this valid JDK configuration. This has nothing to do with Groovy. Plain Java project will fail the same way.

Comment: thanks - that fixed the issue with the syntax error. but still I cannot add Groovy as either an SDK nor a framework. Following this link https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Add_Groovy_SDK_to_IntelliJ_IDEA this was at least possible in the past. Do you know whether this changed?

Comment: As I said, it has changed long time ago, now Groovy is configured by adding a library to the module dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure your JDK configuration is correct.** As @crazycoder commented, OP's is red indicating the path might be incorrect.

Groovy can be added as a module or library in Intellij or dependency in its dependency file (pom.xml, build.gradle etc)

#### 1. [Module (in Intellij)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#remove-dependency):

File > Project Structure <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S</kbd> > click Modules > Dependencies.

[image: Intellij Module dependency]

##### 2. Library (in Intellij):

Go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Project Structure...</kbd> > <kbd>Libraries</kbd> > Click on the plus sign on the leftmost side > Add the Groovy jar or maven source at your choice

[image: Intellij: project structure menu]

##### 3. Dependency (build.gradle):

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0.0'

apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.5"
}
```